# Word usage: Competitive

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning-in-context

> I feel competitive with other parents

This is a quote from a parent workshop. The parents are asked to indicate how well they relate to some statements, the quote being one of them.

I check [https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/competitive#:~:text=%3A%20of%20or%20relating%20to%20a,to%20compete%20successfully%20with%20others](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/competitive#:%7E:text=%3A%20of%20or%20relating%20to%20a,to%20compete%20successfully%20with%20others) and see that competitive has two possible meanings here:

Does competitive here mean the "I" feel that myself is in a competition with other parents?
Or does it mean "I" am desiring to compete with or even win over other parents?

Comment: Either one. It could also mean "I feel equal to other parents" (in parenting abilities, for instance). "Competitive" is often used to mean "equivalent choice", as in phrases like _or competitive products_.

Comment: The quote is ambiguous. It might mean "I feel I am competing against (some of) the other parents," or "When I am in the company of other parents I feel competitive," or, as John Lawler says, "I feel equal to other parents."

Comment: As a former child, and current parent, I can confidently say that there are few things more awful on this earth than competitive parents.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey What about autotune?

Answer (score -1):

> We do feel competitive with each other but we do not begrudge each other's success.”

Of course it depends on the context but it does feel more like :

> "I" feel that myself is in a competition with other parents

[source | lengusa](https://lengusa.com/sentence-examples/feel%20competitive)

Comment: I'd mark ' '"I" feel that myself is in a competition with other parents' incorrect.

Answer (score -3):

competitive is an adjective.
Usually it is good habit to use adjective before nouns. But there are adjective phrases which don't need any **nouns**.

Example -

You are nice. (without noun)

You are a nice **guy**. (with noun)

Your phrase can be - I feel competitive person with other parents